# Setting top margins for TOC and LOF pages

Tags: margins

I need to set the top margin of the first pages in TOC and lof to be 5cm but the rest pages in TOC and LOF are 1cm.

[image: Top margin of the first page of TOC and LOF] 
[image: Top margin in the second page of TOC and LOF]

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen `\cftbeforetoctitleskip` and `\cftbeforeloftitleskip` in the manual of `tocloft`?

Comment: Thanks.! I got a quick look. I may use : \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt} for the first page in toc, how to do it for the second?

Comment: The second etc. pages use the normal page layout, so this should be a `geometry` issue

Comment: I  have the toc in multiple pages, and I want the top margin of those pages to be 1cm. ( it should differ from the page layout). Thanks